# Mongo 3.2 Sub-Document Index issue

Tags: mongodb

Recently we have upgraded our MongoDB 2.6(MMAPV1) to 3.2(MMAPV1), After upgrade indexes in sub-document is not working. I did a small proof of concept on both databases with query explain.

In the MongoDB 3.2, the subdocument index is not considered, can anybody suggest the fix for this?

This is sample mongo document,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58bff13e4e6904293cc206b4"),
    "Value" : NumberLong(158),
    "OVGuid" : NumberLong(0),
    "Name" : "User 08/03/2017 03.55.42.782",
    "CreateDate" : ISODate("2017-03-08T11:55:42.783Z"),
    "RoleLst" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(146),
            "Name" : "Role1"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(108),
            "Name" : "Role2"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(29),
            "Name" : "Role3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I inserted nearly 100,000 data with index enabled on "RoleLst._id"(db.User.createIndex({"RoleLst._id":1})) in both Mongo DB 2.6 and 3.2.

Then I tried query explain

db.User.find({ "RoleLst" : { "$elemMatch" : { "_id" :NumberLong(200)}}}).explain()

This is the result I got from 3.2 is

```
Explain for sub-document query

{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "SubDocmentIndexChecking.User",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "RoleLst" : {
                "$elemMatch" : {
                    "_id" : {
                        "$eq" : NumberLong(200)
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "RoleLst" : {
                    "$elemMatch" : {
                        "_id" : {
                            "$eq" : NumberLong(200)
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "direction" : "forward"
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "******",
        "port" : ******,
        "version" : "3.2.10",
        "gitVersion" : "79d9b3ab5ce20f51c272b4411202710a082d0317"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

This is the result I got from 2.6

```
Explain for sub-document query 
    {
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor RoleLst._id_1",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
        "nscanned" : 0,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 0,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
            "RoleLst._id" : [ 
                [ 
                    NumberLong(200), 
                    NumberLong(200)
                ]
            ]
        },
        "server" : "***********",
        "filterSet" : false,
        "stats" : {
            "type" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
            "works" : 2,
            "yields" : 0,
            "unyields" : 0,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "advanced" : 0,
            "needTime" : 1,
            "needFetch" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "children" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : "FETCH",
                    "works" : 2,
                    "yields" : 0,
                    "unyields" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "advanced" : 0,
                    "needTime" : 1,
                    "needFetch" : 0,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                    "forcedFetches" : 0,
                    "matchTested" : 0,
                    "children" : [ 
                        {
                            "type" : "IXSCAN",
                            "works" : 1,
                            "yields" : 0,
                            "unyields" : 0,
                            "invalidates" : 0,
                            "advanced" : 0,
                            "needTime" : 1,
                            "needFetch" : 0,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "keyPattern" : "{ RoleLst._id: 1.0 }",
                            "isMultiKey" : 1,
                            "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['RoleLst._id']: [200, 200]",
                            "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                            "dupsTested" : 0,
                            "dupsDropped" : 0,
                            "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                            "matchTested" : 0,
                            "keysExamined" : 0,
                            "children" : []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also provide output of `db.User.getIndexes()` ?

Comment: [
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "SubDocmentIndexChecking.User"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "RoleLst._id" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "RoleLst._id_1",
        "ns" : "SubDocmentIndexChecking.User"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "Value" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "Value_1",
        "ns" : "SubDocmentIndexChecking.User"
    }
]

Comment: What will happen if my index is not fit to my RAM? Will the query consider the Index or not

Comment: Try not using `$elemMatch` here as it's not needed. Use this simpler version of the query: `db.User.find({ "RoleLst._id" : NumberLong(200)}).explain()`

Comment: I think my index not fit to the ram that is why this issues came. Now it is working fine.